# Invert transition effect when routing

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to programmatically invert the transition effect to a backwards slide instead a forward slide in SAPUI5?

I want to navigate "back" to the parent element (not a `SplitApp`) when the user user presses a button. The current implementation works, but slides forward, which does not indicate the correct direction:

```
var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
oRouter.navTo('competitions', {
  showId: this.iShowId,
});
```

`navTo` does not seem to have any options for that:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Router.html#navTo

A normal browser-back slides backwards.

What are, if any, my alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you should try assigning "viewLevel" property when specifying navigation targets in the manifest.json file. If you are navigating back to the view with lesser "viewLevel" then UI5 runtime should reverse the effect.

Comment: That sounds great. I will try it. Thank you!
Edit: It worked flawlessly. Will accept asaic